# How can I convert a string with integers to array with integers in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, integer

I want to convert a string with integers to array with integers in Java.
How i can do this?I have an array with strings.Every string is integers.
I want to access every string with a click from a button.

```
 String[] INT_ARRAY={

        //0
        "250,125,20,20,20,40,20,20,20,40,20,20,20,2500",

        //1 
        "233,63,28,63,29,63,28,16,28,17,26,63,29,17,26,16....
                     ........

                 }

   public void onClick(View v) {

        counter++;
        String IntString = INT_ARRAY[counter];

                    String[] parts = IntString.split(",");


          final int[] A = new int[parts.length()];

          for(int i=0; i<parts.length(); i++){

            A[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts(i));

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(A[i]), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

  }
```

Comment: Pretty must the way you have it, but you have to split the string on ,

Comment: why you don't use integer array?

Comment: Why is your `INT_ARRAY` a `String[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Integer[] splitIntegers(String s){
        Object[] numbersAsString = s.split(",");
        return Arrays.copyOf(numbersAsString, numbersAsString.length, Integer[].class);
}
```

Calling:

```
for(String s: INT_ARRAY){
  Integer[] ints = splitIntegers(s);
}
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting to use `Object[]`?

Comment: Avoiding ClassCastException because of the downcast from String to Integer. String can be Object, Object can be Integer, but String cant be Integer (unless parsed or downcasted [if that word suffices])

Comment: Fair enough, I figured that it was better to parse or what have you, but I guess it may just be too verbose for no reason...

Comment: That solution is better than mine if the string has extra characters rather then comma and numbers. Then trimming + replacing + parsing one by one is best solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need [`String#spilt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the string, something like:

```
String[] parts = "aa,bb,cc,dd".split(",");
```

`parts` now consists of `{"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"}`.

Then use the enhanced-for loop to iterate over each part, something like:

```
for(String part : parts) Log.d("", part);
```

Answer (score 3):

So you have a partially-serialized representation of what appears to be an array of integer arrays. From your code, you obviously understand that you need to use `parseInt()` to convert a string representation of an integer to an `int` primitive. This part looks good, but you need logic to loop through each comma-separated value in each string. You can use the `split()` method to create an array of strings from your comma separated list. The entire solution would look like the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    counter++;
    String IntString = INT_ARRAY[counter];

    final String[] vals = IntString.split(","); // Here we split the comma-separated string
    final int[] A = new int[vals.length];

    for(int i=0; i<vals.length; i++){
        A[i] = Integer.parseInt(vals[i]);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(A[i]), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```